# What do standard deviation ellipses mean in an ordination plot?

Tags: vegan

When `kind = 'sd`, `ordiellipse()` draws a single ellipse representing the "standard deviation' around each cluster in an ordination plot.

Generally, I do not know whether such ellipses represent the mean + sd, as one would see in, say, the upper whisker of a barplot, or does whether it means something different in the context of an ordination plot.

What exactly do the standard deviation ellipses represent in an ordination plot?

Comment: If you look up ?ordiellipse it says that:
"standard error of the (weighted) average of scores (kind="sd")"

Comment: Yes, but what is the ellipse plotted relative to? Is it the standard error of the (weighted) average of scores plotted 1 standard error away from the mean score? Or is it plotted 1 standard error away from something else? I would assume the former, but it is not made totally clear by the `help` that `?ordiellipse()` provides.